# How do I run gitlab on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-omnibus

The task I carreid out ↓

0. Hyper-V, Ubuntu 20.04, k8s 1.23.6, Docker 20.10.14 Installation
1. Set up a K8s Cluster(Control Plane 1EA, Worker node 1EA)
2. kubectl apply nginx deployment, nginx service (for test gitlab on k8s)

```
nginx-svc.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort     
  ports:
  - port: 80     
    targetPort: 80   
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

```
nginx-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1           
kind: Deployment              
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment      
  labels:
    app: nginx               
spec:                         
  replicas: 3                 
  selector:                  
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:                 
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:             
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

3. The nginx worked well. But gitlab has a problem.

```
gitlab-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1           
kind: Deployment              
metadata:
  name: gitlab-deployment      
  labels:
    app: gitlab                
spec:                         
  replicas: 1                
  selector:                   
    matchLabels:
      app: gitlab
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:                 
        app: gitlab
    spec:
      containers:             
      - name: gitlab
        image: gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9088
        - containerPort: 10022
```

```
gitlab-svc.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gitlab-svc
  labels:
    app: gitlab
spec:
  type: NodePort     
  ports:
  - port: 9088     
    targetPort: 9088
    name: http
  - port : 10022
    targetPort: 10022
    name: ssh
  selector:
    app: gitlab
```

4. modify gitlab.rb file (etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb in k8s pod)
   .
   .
   .
   external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:9088
   .
   .
   gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022"
   .
   .
   .
5. Input url workernodeIP:NodePort(gitlabsvc) but can't access..
   The port of the container in the pod does not open either.

I don't use helm, EKS, GKS, etc.
After installing Kubernetes on my hyper-v virtual machine, I want to run gitlab on it.
(Like running a gitlab image with a docker)
I only want to run gitlab locally using Kubernetes and gitlab images......

Comment: What is the link between nginx and gitlab here ? I mean why deploying a nginx exactly?

Comment: Do you have an ingress controller to redirect traffic to your service?

Comment: What is the status of the pod? What are the logs?

Comment: 1. What is the link between nginx and gitlab here ? I mean why deploying a nginx exactly?

-> There is no link between gitlab and nginx. The reason for deploying nginx was to test whether the yaml file was the appropriate yaml file.
If the nginx yaml file is an appropriate file, I thought that the gitlab would run well when only the image was changed to gitlab.

2. Do you have an ingress controller to redirect traffic to your service?

-> The Ingress controller is not used. I use only nodeport.

Comment: 3. What is the status of the pod? What are the logs?

-> kubectl get pod
 NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
gitlab-deployment-6c59865b74-8wbq2   1/1     Running   0          12m

kubectl describe pod gitlab-deployment-6c59865b74-8wbq2
Successfully..Pulling image "gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest.. Successfully pulled image "gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest" in 1m31.4383413s...Created container gitlab...Started container gitlab.. => maybe No problem..

Answer (score 0):

If your pod is running correctly try:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/NAME_OF_THE_POD 8080:9088
```

... On your local machine browser to check if the service works properly.

If this work, do the same with the service

```
kubectl port-forward service/gitlab-svc 8080:9088
```

The nodePort service type expose the application on the port specified of your worker node machine.
If both above commands worked try to check network issues.

Please answer my comments under your questions, that way I can give you more help

Comment: my pod is running correctly, and i try kubectl port-forward pod/NAME_OF_THE_POD 8080:9088  and result : Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 9088, Forwarding from[::1]:8080 -> 9088    checked my local machine browser but service works not properly.

Comment: Now, I am checking the difference between running gitlab on docker(not using k8s, only docker) and running gitlab on kubernetes. This is because the result value is different when I access the container and pod and enter gitlab-ctl status.